# Avoiding Content re-fetching when State has already populated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redux, vuex

I have the following Vue components structure:

```
Wrapper
-- QuestionsList
---- Question
-- QuestionDetail
```

And the following routes:

```
/ (goes to Questionslist)
/:id (goes to QuestionDetail)
```

When the user visits `/`, an HTTP GET request is done (via Vuex) and content is populated in an array of objects. Then, if he clicks on a "show more" link, he sees the `QuestionDetail` page (but without having to re-fetch content - it's taken directly from the `State`)

My problem is that every time we "route" in a page, we're not aware of the state of our Store.

For example, when the user navigates (deep-linked) to `/:id`, we need to see if the State is populated and therefore avoid making a new HTTP GET:

```
created() {
  if (!this.$store.state.questions.length) {
    this.$store.dispatch('requestItems');
  }
},
computed: {
  question() {
    return this.$store.state.questions[this.$route.params.id] || {};
  },
},
```

On a different scenario, since I always concat the new items fetched with the current state,I often see that data is duplicated:

```
  [types.FETCHED_ADS_SUCCESS](state, payload) {
    state.items = [...state.items, ...payload]; // when I go back in history, a new action is initiated and concats a copy of the same data
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your store structure? I have found it useful to keep a boolean indicator in the store to indicate whether the content is loaded or not.

```
const store = new Vuex.store({
  state: {
    questions: {
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    }
  }
})
```

Then in the component where you're fetching the questions check for this and update once loaded.

Comment: interesting. I think as a quick solution that'll work